# Sqlite Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android, sql

My Log cat.

```
09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method 
of the activity

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3609)

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085)

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3604)
09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    ... 11 more

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

09-27 21:00:42.414: E/AndroidRuntime(29268):    at 
com.shikkhok.taskmanagement.MainActivity.save(MainActivity.java:38)
```

And This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText etName, etEmail, etPhone, etDesignation;
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    // declare view
    ListView lvEmployees;
    // declare adapter
    CustomizedAdapter adapter;

    // datasource

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);


        lvEmployees = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvEmployees);
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    }

    public void save(View v) {
        String name = etName.getText().toString();
        String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        String phone = etPhone.getText().toString();
        String designation = etDesignation.getText().toString();

        Employee employee = new Employee(name, email, phone, designation);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), employee.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        long inserted = dbHelper.insertEmployee(employee);
        if (inserted >= 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data inserted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data insertion failed...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    public void view(View v) {
        ArrayList<Employee> employees = dbHelper.getAllEmployees();
        if (employees != null && employees.size() > 0) {
            adapter = new CustomizedAdapter(this, employees);
            lvEmployees.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


    }

}
```

When i pressed the save Button this Logcat error show in my eclipse How to solve it.

Comment: What's line MainActivity.java:38?

Comment: I don't know.
What is the error.@MysticMagic

Comment: This is not a correct answer the error was in Emloyee constractor.
Thnx.@MysticMagic

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, as it seems from your code and logcat, error is on

```
String phone = etPhone.getText().toString();
String designation = etDesignation.getText().toString();
```

these lines.

In your `onCreate` you have initialized `etName` and `etEmail`. But not `etPhone` or `etDesignation`

You would need to initialize them, as you did with `etName` and `etEmail`.

```
etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDesignation);
```

Hope it helps.